# How to create a group in WSO2 Store

Tags: api, wso2

I have some APIs in WSO2 store, and some of them are grouped.

**How can I create a new group and put APIs in it?**

The project has been given to me without much info, and I've searched a lot about creating new groups, but with no success. My version is 2011-2013.

Comment: What do you mean by `the version is 2011-2013`?

Comment: please have a look at `repository/conf/carbon.xml` and look for tag `Version`. As far I know groups (as posted in the answer) are supported from version 2.0.0 or 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WSO2 API Manager, APIs are grouped by tags. When you create an API from `publisher`, you can assign tags for your APIs. Then you can filter APIs by those tags in `store`.

There is a special set of tags which are called groups.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Customizing+the+API+Store#CustomizingtheAPIStore-CategorizingandgroupingAPIs

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed!